# Why substitution can be used to get Taylor Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

See the example in: [How to find the Maclaurin series for $e^{-x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218711/how-to-find-the-maclaurin-series-for-e-x2)

If I use $t$ to substitute some function $F(x)$, then the series got still is $t$. So how can I decide under what circumstance the substitution works and what does not?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Looking at the answer, I was uncertain what $t$ was supposed to mean.

Comment: Do you mean, when can you substitute a function in for the variable in a taylor series?

Comment: @AlexS Yes. Or how to judge whether the result got by substitution is correct?

Answer (score 0):

It will always work. When you make a substitution all you are doing is taking one quantity and expressing it differently. But each quantity is still equal. So if you know that $$e^t = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}$$ and you know it holds for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (in particular when $t$ is negative), then it is obvious that we can choose $x = \sqrt{-t}$ to get $t= -x^2$. Since the quantities are equal it is also obvious that $$e^{-x^{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kx^{2k}}{k!}$$

Comment: I understand what you say. But the problem is, why the coefficient for each term in the result is the corresponding coefficient in Taylor series? Why (-1)^k/k!=f^2k(e^-x^2) ?

Comment: @Samara i'm not sure I follow your equation there... What is $f$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. "Why (-1)^k/k! is equal to the radio of 2k derivative of e^(-x^2) and (2k)!  ?"

Comment: I still don't underestand "the radio of 2k derivative of e^(-x^2) and (2k)! " I assume you mean "ratio" instead of radio, but what does the derivative have to do with this? And what does a ratio have to do with this? It really is as simple as $t^k = (-x^2)^k = (-1)^k(x^2)^k = (-1)^kx^{2k}$

Comment: the formula to get the coefficient of each term in Taylor series is the nth derivative of a function to n!. When using substitution to get the series, you automatically admit the coefficients are equal those ratios.

Comment: So you are trying to derive it by scratch? I'm still not sure why you feel that there is a problem with this method, if we agree that $t$ and $-x^2$ are equal quantities

Comment: A function can be equal to many series(I think). why the series got must be Taylor series?

Comment: @Samara If a function has a taylor series expansion, it has exactly one.

Comment: Yes. It has one Taylor series. But is there another way to express the function by writing some terms?

Comment: @Samara I do not believe so. There are other types of series,  like the more general Laurent series or the Fourier series (you can't express $e^{-x^{2}}$ with a Fourier series expansion).  But your initial question was about Taylor series so I didn't think you were interested in expressing it in other ways?

Comment: In my original question, I do give an example: what if I substitute the whole function with one variable t. Then I find the Taylor series for the liner function, y=t, which turns out to be itself. So such a substitution clearly does not work, meaning not all substitutions work. That's how my question comes out.